# There is no homeomorphic copy of $[0,1]$ in the plane which contains an open ball

Tags: general-topology

Problem: Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ be homeomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$.  Then $A$ contains no nonempty open set of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

What I've got so far: if it does, then it contains an open ball, say $O$.  Since $[0,1]$ is compact and path connected, so is $A$, and in particular $A$ is closed.  Thus $\overline{O} \subseteq \overline{A} = A$, meaning $A \setminus O$ contains the boundary of $O$.

I think that $A \setminus O$ should be path connected; if $x, y \in A \setminus O$, we already know there is a path $\tau$ in $A$ which goes from $x$ to $y$.  If this path doesn't go through $O$, no problem; if it does, by compactness (somehow) we should be able to find an interval $(c,d) \subseteq [0,1]$ for which $\tau(c), \tau(d) \in \overline{O}$ and $\tau(t) \in O$ only for values of $t \in (c,d)$.  On $(c,d)$ we can then reroute $\tau$ to go along the boundary of $O$.

If $f: A \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a homeomorphism, the fact that $A \setminus O$ is path connected means that $[0,1] \setminus f(O)$ should also be path connected. $f(O)$ is open in $[0,1]$, so it would be nice if I could assume that $f(O)$ contained some interval $(a,b)$ for $0 < a < b$, so then $[0,1] \setminus f(O)$ wouldn't be path connected, a contradiction.  But how do I know that $f(O)$ isn't an open set of the form $[0,b)$ for $b < 1$ (so that $[0,1] \setminus f(O)$ is still path connected)?

Comment: If the image of the interval contained an open ball in the plane, then you could remove three points from this ball and the image less these three points would remain connected. But the restriction of the inverse of the homeomorphism to this connected thrice-punctured set would be a homeomorphism back to the thrice-punctured interval, which can't be connected, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f^{-1}(0)$ or $f^{-1}(1)$ is in $O$, you can take a smaller open ball contained in $O$ that avoids them.

Comment: So simple..thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:A \to [0,1]$ be the homeomorphism. Suppose $B(x_0,\epsilon) \subset A$.

Suppose $f(x_0) \in (0,1)$, then $f(B(x_0, \epsilon) \setminus \{x_0\}) = [0,1] \setminus \{f(x_0) \}$. However, then first set is connected and the second is not
which contradicts $f$ being continuous.

Hence we must have $f(x_0) \in \{0,1\}$. Since every point in $B(x_0, \epsilon)$ lies inside another open ball, we have $f(x) \in \{0,1\}$ for all
$x \in B(x_0, \epsilon)$.
This contradicts the fact that $f$ is a bijection.

Hence $A$ contains no open set.